# MongoDB saving _id as a string (java)

Tags: java, mongodb

I have an object that has a parent class that may or may not set a _id field.

In this case, the _id field is not set and I pass an object through to

collection.insertOne(object)

Normally mongo generates a ObjectId() for a _id that isn't specified, but for some reason whenever _id is specified by a parent class and is not set, it is generating an id, bug is saving the id as a string in the database rather than an ObjectId.

What I'm passing through

{
  "name" : "name"
}

Expected:

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5cb89a7cf5e722a3d493ce8b"),
  "name" : "name"
}

Actual:

{
  "_id" : "5cb89a7cf5e722a3d493ce8b",
  "name" : "name"
}

What I think is happening is that it sees that the parent class has a _id field, but can't find it, causing somthing like this to be passed through.

{
  "_id" : null,
  "name" : "name"
}

and as a result mongo doesn't generate an ObjectId but a string.

Is this a bug?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to declare the _id as ObjectId ?

Comment: There are other classes that require this to not always be an object id but as a string.

Comment: I'm trying to upgrade to mongo 4 and it is giving me this issue. Our previous version of mongo saved it as an objectId. (Mongo v3.4.14)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the normal behavior of mongoDB. I only use mongo with javascript and this is the behavior it always shows. I‘m wondering if this actually makes any difference for your usecase, as the id is still unique

Comment: When retrieving these objects from the database, we are expecting it to be of type ObjectId, and other objects of the same parent type, we could be expecting them to be strings. We handle it differently depending on the type. It would be preferred to not have to check each time what type of object it is returned (but may have to if there are no other solutions). Plus it doesn't look quite right having a different type _id for the same object.

Comment: I think you have to manually overwrite _id and create an ObjectId on that field